# Symfony 3.0 routing failing - router:match and debug:router contradictory results

Tags: symfony

I have got a strange problem with routing in Symfony 3.0

My controller code looks like this:

```
  /**
 * @Route("/dokumenty/plik/{dok_id}/{plik_id}", defaults={"plik_id" = "nowy"}, name="dokument_plik")
 * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
 */
```

but whenever I try to access `/dokumenty/plik/1/` or `/dokumenty/plik/1/1/` I get the routing error:

> No route found for "GET /dokumenty/plik/1/"

I have tried to debug the routing from console using `php bin/console debug:router` and I got inter alia the following route listed

> dokument_plik ANY ANY ANY /dokumenty/plik/{dok_id}/{plik_id}

At the same time when I use  `php bin/console router:match dokumenty/plik/1/1/` i get:

> [ERROR] None of the routes match the path "dokumenty/plik/1/1/"

At results of both commands seems contradictory I am a little confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its about last slash. Try /dokumenty/plik/1

Comment: And in case you really need the trailing slash, take a look here for an example of a route that works with or without one. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html